# Looping Through JavaScript Array of Objects and Removing Values

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, vue.js

I'm working with Vue and Rails.  The goal of the code below is remove text from input fields when users toggle between adding a new recipe and going back to the main page. This works with all my fields except for ingredients.

Ingredients is an array that belongs to the recipe object and holds a name in a key value pair. I want to loop through this and remove all the ingredients. I do that by calling the removeIngredients function. The problem is when I execute the code below, the loop only grabs every other index and thus only half of the ingredients are deleted.

```
resetNewRecipe: function(){
    this.recipe.name = '';
    this.recipe.chef = '';
    this.recipe.cooktime = '';
    this.recipe.amount = '',
    this.recipe.description = '';
    this.recipe.favorite = false;
    this.recipe.ingredients.name = '';
    for (i = 0; i < this.recipe.ingredients.length; i++){

      for (var name in this.recipe.ingredients[i]){

        if (this.recipe.ingredients[i].hasOwnProperty(name)){
          console.log("name = " + name);
          console.log("i = " + i);
          console.log("this.recipe.ingredients[i][name] " + this.recipe.ingredients[i][name]);

          this.removeIngredient(i);
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

The recipe object code

```
recipe: {
    name: '',
    chef: '',
    cooktime: '',
    amount: '',
    description: '',
    favorite: false,
    ingredients: [
      {name: ''},
    ]}
```

Console.log returns when I create four ingredients each named 1,2,3,4. Basically 1 and 3 get passed successfully and are deleted, while 2 and 4 remain when I return back to the form.

```
name = name
i = 0
this.recipe.ingredients[i][name] 1

name = name
i = 1
this.recipe.ingredients[i][name] 3
```

Comment: why not just `this.recipes.ingredients = []` instead of looping through each since you just want to reset the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate backwards through the array, so from the last index to 0. That way you will get to delete them all. Also, you should break out of the inner loop when you actually delete one:

```
for (var i = this.recipe.ingredients.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){ // <-- change direction
  for (var name in this.recipe.ingredients[i]){
    if (this.recipe.ingredients[i].hasOwnProperty(name)){
      this.removeIngredient(i);
      break; // <------ add this
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you so much for your help.